# Clirr Doesn't Acknowledge Semantic Version

Tags: maven

I tried to get [Clirr](http://www.mojohaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/) to work, but since there is almost no documentation (that I could find) it's really hard:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works for detecting API breaks, but for some reason it doesn't seem to take the version of the current artifact into account.

For instance adding a method into an interface while changing the version from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0 should not make the build fail.

Is there any way to get Clirr to acknowledge semantic versioning?

Comment: Doc is here http://www.mojohaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html Doesn't look like it can do what you need here though.

Comment: @Tunaki Okay, then that's the answer I guess.